# Disk Partition not showing up

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I feel I'm obliged to say that I'm a total Linux/Ubuntu newbie. I have always been a Windows user and the whole Ubuntu system is completely new to me.
I have a 1 Tb hard disk which under Win7 was separated into 3 partitions -C (system part), D and E. I keep my movies, music and files on D, used C for installed programs and Kept E completely free. When I installed Ubuntu 15.04 I selectedd E partition as Linux' system dir. After installation however, that E partition completely disappeared. I can still see my C and D, but E is not visible on neither Win nor Linux. In win's disk manager it is displayed as unattached? space, while on Linux it shows as Linux filesystem. I can't understand what's going on and will be really thankful for any replies :)
P.S Here's a screenshot if it helps somehow.
http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/600/8372600z.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows use NTFS partitions; Linux, ext4... Linux is able to read and write NTFS without need of any tweaks, but our loved Windows is unable to do the opposite: it does not support natively ext4 partitions. But don't dismay, because it can be fixed using Ext2File, an open source Linux ext2/ext3/ext4 file system driver for Windows systems... you can find it [here](http://www.ext2fsd.com/).

When you're installing, you can make it start automatically when Windows boots... I suggest you not to enable write support in order to avoid any troubles: first, ext4 writing support is not ready yet; second, windows could do messy things. With this application you can assign a letter to any Linux partition.

There is a blog that talks about this utility usage, it's on spanish but it has some pictures you could use as a guide. Hope it works for you as it did for me.

Abraham Medina

PD: Linux names NTFS partitions with its storage capacity... something like "329 GB volume". You won't see your Linux partition this way, but "File System".

Comment: You're very welcome, @DanailNedkov. ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Linux does not name partitions with letters C, D, like in Windows.
2. Linux partitions can not be accessed from Windows, unless special drivers are installed there.
3. If you installed Ubuntu to your "E" partition, it is the normal situation that it is not "seen" from Windows and is used by Ubuntu without any C, D, etc. letters.
4. You can browse the Linux partition by clicking "Computer" in you Nautilus file manager.

So, there is no problem at all.

Comment: Yeah I get that I cant see it from Windows but the probkem is I can't see it on Linux either

Comment: You do see it from Linux. But it is not called "Disk E". Just click "Computer" in nautilus and you will be able to browse the linux partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can see windows partitions from ubuntu. To mount windows partitions in ubuntu some changes needed in windows OS. 1) Go to power option 2) choose what the power buttons do 3) below in shutdown setting  turn off fast startup setting 4) save changes. Shut down pc and start ubuntu. And you can access windows partitions .